# What noun means "the state of being intrigued/amazed by something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What noun means "the state of being intrigued/amazed by something"?

For example, the state of *being poor* is **poverty**.

Is there such a word for *being intrigued/amazed*?

Answer (score 5):

This may be a bit too direct, but

- the state of being amazed is [***amazement***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amazement).
- the state of being intrigued is [***curiosity***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curiosity), [***wonder***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonder), or [***fascination***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fascination).

The exact word which fits your purpose best will depend on the context, but in my mind amazement simply implies being surprised, shocked, or dazzled while the other words imply that *as well as* an intense interest to discover more about the subject. In that sense *curiosity*, *wonder*, and *fascination* are broader, more encompassing terms than mere *amazement*.

Any of them would probably be a good fit, but *fascination* seems to come closest to expressing the same 'dazzled' sense as *amazement*, while also expressing intrigue.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider:

[***awe***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/awe) (n) 1. A mixed emotion of reverence, respect, dread, and wonder inspired by authority, genius, great beauty, sublimity, or might: *We felt **awe** when contemplating the works of Bach. The observers were in **awe** of the destructive power of the new weapon.*

Comment: +1 *Awe* is good, but to me it suffers the same problem as *amazement*--merely describing the emotional surprise of being *amazed*, and not the interest to discover implied by being *intrigued*.

Comment: @p.s.w.g You read my mind! I did want to stress the interest to discover.

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend *[wonderment](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wonderment)*:

> **wonderment**, *n.*:
>
> **1** astonishment, awe, or puzzlement
>
> **2** something that produces wonder; a marvel

Note that *wonderment* captures both *astonishment* and *puzzlement*, a close cousin to *intrigue* (which M-W defines as "to arouse the interest, desire, or curiosity of (as by *beguiling or baffling*)").

Comment: This was going to be my response too.